# How to change default screenshot application on macOS?

Tags: macos, hotkeys, screenshot

I want to keep the default shortcuts for taking a screenshot (physical button on my keychron keyboard and <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>) but instead of using built in tool that lacks a lot of features and is not very user friendly in my opinion.

I want to open a Flameshot screenshot software even if it is not launched and visible in my task bar just as I was able to do this with any Linux machine.

I don't have problem if it would require special program or some script writing to get it to work.

Comment: Cmd/Shift/5 has a lot more options. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460089/how-to-launch-an-application-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/460091#460091 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464293/how-do-i-add-change-or-remove-a-key-command-shortcut-from-a-menu-item